# Youtube video behaviour when zooming in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, youtube

For some reason [my web page](http://www.streetstyles4all.co.uk) is not display correctly in Firefox. It is displayed correctly in IE9, Safari, chrome.

In Firefox if I **zoom** out or in the layout changes. But then the **YouTube video begins to smear and pixelate**. I asked a friend to check Firefox on their computer and the same thing happens.

Comment: Am quiet surprised by reading that IE supports and Firefox doesn't..

Comment: did some 1 noticed a cool behavior in here, if you load the website and go to bottom of the page the containers flow out of the white area, now zoom out the page by pressing `ctrl & - keys` and than reset it by pressing `ctrl+0` n wolaa..containers are proper

Comment: BTW: "Street Styles 4 All trailer" => "This video contains content from SME and UMG, one or more of whom have blocked it in your country on copyright grounds. 
Sorry about that."

Comment: The video works in the UK, but I think it is blocked in Germany, according t youtube.  Does it not work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add `<div class="clear"></div>` after your last update div which have latest news `<div class="updates"></div>`

Comment: Thank you for that solution.  The layout is now fine but now the youtube video still pixelates and acts funny but only in firefox and only when I scroll up and down!

Comment: at my side everything looking fine will you upload a screenshot what's the issue so i can help you better